# Getting Consumer Secret Via API

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps

I'm trying to automatically create apps in new pods as they are added. When I create apps, I'm able to get all the values but Consumer Key. Is there a way to get it through code? I know it's protected. I'm just wondering if there is a method to get the value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth configs are automatically shared across all of salesforce for you, you don't need to replicate them yourself to pods or orgs.

Comment: Hi, I want it outside the org, in a different project, so that I can use the key and the secret to get access tokens.

Comment: I guess i don't follow your use-case, you can create one and use it everywhere, why do you need to programatically create & fetch them?

Comment: I'm trying to get some data of a particular user in each and every pod. All these users are different for each pod. To get those data with REST API I need access token. To get access token I need consumer key and secret. I want to do it programmatically 'cause I want it as automated as possible i.e if new pods get added, this does things automatically.

Comment: but you can create one consumer key and use it with every user in every pod, you don't need to keep creating new one.

Comment: I tried that too. I created a connected app in cs12 for the user monitor@cs12.salesforce.com  But when I tried the access token I got for some other pod, it throws error.

Comment: its takes a little time to replicate but should work fine after that.

Comment: I tried it many times and I created the app a couple of days ago. I don't know what problem it does have.

Comment: I think the problem here is, I'm creating apps in cs instances (not in production). But this is what i need to do. Is there a way to do this?